# Excel blank cell reference to add cell next to it twice

Tags: arrays, excel

Is there a way to sum a row of cells up, but if a cell in the row is blank then add the cell on the left side of the blank cell two times?

UPDATE:

Thank you! This works but one glitchy portion that I found. For my data, If I have a construction job that last 12 days with no off day (off days are what I am considering blank). and the job is complete, Then the formula should only add from the first numbered cell to the last numbered cell. In the results bellow, with your formula, it adds the blank cell at the very end as well. It should read 60 and not 65. How would I create a formula to read from first to last number in row only? See snip bellow:

[image]

Comment: Please, provide a simple of your data, besides your required answer.

Comment: Please, provide a simple of your data, besides your required answer.

Comment: See my edited answer.  Kindly accept and upvote if it served the purpose and helped.  :)

Answer (score 1):

**Addition as per updated question**

Use this `array formula` to cater to these kind of situation ( with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd> )

```
=IF(ISBLANK(N2), IF(ISBLANK(M2), SUM(IF(COLUMN(A2:L2)<=COLUMNS(B2:L2),ISBLANK(B2:L2))*A2:L2)+SUM(A2:L2), SUM(IF(COLUMN(A2:M2)<=COLUMNS(B2:M2),ISBLANK(B2:M2))*A2:M2)+SUM(A2:M2)),SUM(IF(COLUMN(A2:N2)<=COLUMNS(B2:N2),ISBLANK(B2:N2))*A2:N2)+SUM(A2:N2))
```

see screenshot

[image]

This will cater to following situations-

- Obviously blanks in first cell doesn't matter
- If there are multiple/single blanks at the end of the job period, it won't consider any of them.
- however, it assumes that there aren't more than one consecutive blank intermediate.  If there are, it will consider working hours for one of those only because immediate left of second of two consecutive blanks will be a blank only. (see row A4 to N4 in above screenshot)

**OLD answer** suppose your data is in A1:K1

[image]

Add any dummy text in cell next to it `L1` (which can be a hidden column), thereafter add this formula in the cell next to it `M1`

```
=SUM(A1:K1, SUMPRODUCT((A1:K1)*ISBLANK(B1:L1)))
```

You'll get your results

[image]

Comment: Thank you, please ready comment above. This formula works but have one other question.

Comment: You have actually changed your question now to a different scenario, without either accepting or upvoting the helpful answer.  For a changed scenario, you should have put up a separate question.  However, let me figure out something

Comment: Edited the answer as per modified condition